# Untyped global name 'sum_': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I am getting the error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'sum_': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
```

for the following code:

```
import numba as nb
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('yin')

@cc.export('sum_', nb.float32(nb.float32[:]))
def sum_(a):
    s = 0
    for i in a:
        s += i
    return s

@cc.export('average', nb.float32(nb.float32[:]))
def average(a):
    return sum_(a)/len(a)

cc.compile()
```

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this problem once before. The ahead-of-time compilation mode doesn't help in type inference, for some reason, unlike `jit` or `njit` compiled functions. A workaround, as suggested [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3632), would be to add an additional `njit` decorator.

```
import numba as nb
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('yin')

@nb.njit
@cc.export('sum_', nb.float32(nb.float32[:]))
def sum_(a):
    s = 0
    for i in a:
        s += i
    return s

@cc.export('average', nb.float32(nb.float32[:]))
def average(a):
    return sum_(a)/len(a)

cc.compile()
```